# C++ Passing a pointer to a member function as an argument

Tags: c++

I need to pass a pointer to a member function as an argument to a member function in another class. What I'm doing is something like below.
I want to call int Processor::AddJob(void *(*_pFunc)(void*), void* _pArg) method with void* ProcessHandler::Task(void* a) as the first argument.
I did it as

```
TaskFunc pFunc1 = &ProcessHandler::Task;
p_Processor->AddJob(pFunc1,10);
```

But it gives the error

> error: no matching function for call to Processor::AddJob(void*
>   (ProcessHandler::*&)(void*), int)’ Processor.h:47: note: candidates
>   are: int Processor::AddJob(void* (*)(void*), void*)

Can someone please help me on this.My implementation is as follows.(Not the exact code-it is much larger than this)

```
class Processor 
{
public:
    Processor();
    virtual ~Processor();

    int AddJob(void *(*_pFunc)(void*), void* _pArg);
};

int Processor::AddJob(void *(*_pFunc)(void*), void* _pArg)
{
    //Job addition related code goes here
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
typedef void* (ProcessHandler::*TaskFunc)(void*); 
class ProcessHandler
{
public:
    ProcessHandler(Processor* _pProcessor);
    virtual ~ProcessHandler();
    void* Task(void* a);
    void Init();

private:
    Processor* p_Processor;
};


void* ProcessHandler::Task(void* a)
{
    //Task related code goes here
}

void ProcessHandler::Init()
{
    TaskFunc pFunc1 = &ProcessHandler::Task;
    p_Processor->AddJob(pFunc1,10); //This give the compile error.
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    Processor* pProcessor = new Processor();
    ProcessHandler* pProcessHandler = new ProcessHandler(pProcessor);
    pProcessHandler->Init();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

void *(*_pFunc)(void*) is a C-Function pointer, and as such, you can only either pass C-Functions via that pointer, or static functions.

```
void (ProcessHandler::*)(void); //Since you already have a Typedef, pass that as 'type'
```

should help you call a member function.
Call it with the pointer to member function calling syntax:

```
(objectPointer->*functionPointer)();
```

Comment: using static functions is not much clear to me . Can I just do that by declaring the below function as static? But it gives the same error.                                                          void* ProcessHandler::Task(void* a)
{
    //Task related code goes here
}

Comment: @user1308004 Technically, yes, just like that. 

static void* ProcessHandler::Task(void* a); in header file and void* ProcessHandler::Task(void* a) in CPP file.

You can have a pointer to that one with the function signature void * (*)(void);
Look here for further information: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Comment: The syntax for function call is `(objectPointer->*functionPointer)();`

Answer (score 3):

You can only pass static member functions via the address-of operator. Regular member functions don't work. You should consider using std::function.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to solve this using static functions. I'm not clear on that

Answer (score 1):

In C++ I would suggest to do_NOT use pointers to functions(raw pointers are arguable too).
You should use std::function(boost::function) for more generality, or 
template. Latter gives you a bit perfomance, but less typecheck.